# Is there any way to charge card from iOS App without backend charge from our server.(Stripe - iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

i am using **Stripe** for payment. i want to charge card from my App. currently i am using below code to charge card but the process is done from server side. is there any way to charge card from app instead of sending the stripeToken to a server?

```
-(void)createBackendChargeWithToken:(STPToken *)token completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus))completion {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/token"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    NSString *body     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"stripeToken=%@&amount=%@", token.tokenId,_txtAmount.text];
    request.HTTPBody   = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task =
    [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
               completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                   NSURLResponse *response,
                                   NSError *error) {
                   if (error) {
                       completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);
                       // [self customeAlertView:@"Payment not successful" message:@"Please try again later."];
                       NSLog(@"Payment not successful. Please try again later.");
                   } else {
                       completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusSuccess);
                       // [self customeAlertView:@"Success" message:@"Please enjoy your new purchase."];
                       NSLog(@"Payment Success. Please enjoy your new purchase.");
                   }
               }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: see this once may be it helps you https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik also i have checked it but all codes for backend charges from server.

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not possible. Stripe's [iOS](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) and [Android](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android) bindings are only used to collect card information and create tokens, much like [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) and [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) do in a web application.

Once the token has been created, it must be sent to an external server where you can use it in API requests, e.g. to [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

The reason an external server must be used is that all API requests besides token creation must be issued using your secret API key, which must not be used directly into your application, otherwise malicious users will be able to retrieve it and use it to access your account.